# How to display HTML formatted text in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using HTML rich text editor in my Asp.net project and I saved some HTML content to database. Now I want to display those formatted text in Crystal reports so I have done following steps..

1. Right click on my field and selected "Format Object"
2. Went to "Paragraph" Tab
3. Selected "HTML Text" option from "Text Interpretation"

Everything is good but it's not showing the color because I have set the font color black. My HTML content contains some words in color like this

```
<p>This is <span style="color:red">Red</span></p>
```

If I set the formula in "Font" property of my field, it will color the whole content.

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to fall back to old school HTML:

```
<p>This is <font color="red">Red</font></p>
```

Crystal Reports does not have an advanced HTML renderer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Old School HTML" here?  HTML4 vs 5?

Comment: Yes, indeed: HTML 4 ... but probably still with some limitations, I guess somewhat similar how Outlook works with HTML mails. You'll have to dive into the Crystal Reports specifications for the details.